# Does anyone have any example code for node-sqlite3 "Full Buffer/Blob support"?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, blob

We have very large (gigs) size files we must read and then store in an node-sqlite3 blob. I note that docs say it is now supported...but have been unable to find any example code. Have you seen any or have any idea where I might look?

ref: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to [Read Data From A BLOB Incrementally](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_read.html) from Node. Node-sqlite3 does NOT yet support this: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/424.

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code which may help you.

```
var sqlite3 = require('..'),
var fs = require('fs'),
var total = 10;
var bData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'FilePath');

 var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:'); //Database path
 db.run("CREATE TABLE Bdata (id INT, image BLOB)", done);
 db.run('INSERT INTO Bdata (id, image) VALUES (?, ?)', 1, bData, function(err)    
   {
      if (err) throw err;
   });
 }
 db.close();
```

More sample example you can find here.
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/tree/master/test